# Unity orthographic camera size property

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, orthographic

I have an orthographic camera. The values of the viewport rect are as follows...

```
x = 0
y = 0
W = 1
H = 1
```

Let's say I have two cubes both of scale 1. One is at x = 0 and one is at x = 1. Now let's say the orthographic camera is at x = 0.5 (midway between the cubes), above the cubes looking down on them, what size do I need to make the camera in order for the cubes to take up the entire width of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you're trying to use the viewport rect?
If you're only trying to get them the cubes to fit, it's best to just change the Orthographic Size of camera.

[Link to Unity's API on Camera.orthoGraphic size](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-orthographicSize.html)

If you're trying to fit them exactly into the **width** of the camera, then you'd have to change the orthographic size depending on the aspect ratio.
If you're trying to fit them exactly into the **height** however, the orthographic size will be 1.

Comment: I'm not modifying the size of the viewport rect, I want to modify the size of the orthographic camera

Comment: Ah, since you stated in your question the values of your viewport rect, I assumed you were trying to modify those values. I should probably  have read the question completely. My mistake. However, the rest of the answer still applies.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on how I'm supposed to change the width dependent on the aspect ratio? Maybe with a formula or something?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can use this code to make the orthographic size of camera different according to the different screen sizes .

Check out the chunk of code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraScaler : MonoBehaviour {

    public float scrnHeight =800f;
    public float scrnWidth =480f;
    public float tempRation = 1;
    public const float fixedValue = 3f ;
    //public Vector2 nativeRes = new Vector2 (480,800);

    void Awake()
    {
        scrnHeight = Screen.height;
        scrnWidth = Screen.width;
        tempRation = scrnWidth / scrnHeight;
        Debug.Log (Screen.height);
        Debug.Log (Screen.width);
        Debug.Log (tempRation);
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = fixedValue / tempRation;



    }
}
```